# TYPO3 content element margins cannot be set in BE

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I've a problem with TYPO3 content element margins. I am using TYPO3 version 4.7.2.
When I set margins in the 'Appearance' tab - 'Content Element 
Layout', Top Margin and Bottom Margin, the margins are not recognized and 
displayed in FE.

I've added a typoscript code "tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap >" in my TS template setup and it's not working.

Comment: Two ideas: 1) have you included the typoscript for CSS-styled-content? 2) Are you using floats? Do the margins appear in Firebug or some other developer tool (with/without your line of TS)?

Comment: How does your html source in frontend look like for that element?

Comment: I've got the answer.Actual reason is "tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap" is override with some other properties.I've removed it. Thanks for your feedbacks..

Comment: Would you close this question then, please?

Comment: Please close the question by answering it yourself or deleting it.